# link to WhatsApp from a different app send file/image instead of text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, whatsapp

I want to send PDF file and Image to whatsApp.
below method is for text. I want to send **ABC.pdf** instead of **urlendcodedtext**

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=urlencodedtext">Share this</a>
```

I want this

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=ABC.pdf">Share this</a>
or 
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=image.png">Share this</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible?

Comment: Have a read up of the `share extension` section of https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=en

Comment: @ChrisG I have no idea. What to do now ?

Comment: @JoeyM, this is for react native, the OP is asking about react for web

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way. Save the source file somewhere and then pass the URL in text.

```
const shareToWhatsApp = () => {
    let newURL = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text= https://example.com/files/test-file}`;
    window.open(newURL, "_blank");
  }
```